# Naming array method 'to_hash' causes 'stack level too deep' error

Tags: ruby

I tried to create a 'to_hash' array method, but kept getting 'stack level too deep' errors:

```
class Array
  def to_hash
    Hash[self.each_index.zip(self)]
  end
end

puts [50, 49, 53, 44].to_hash

# SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

I finally worked out that the method name 'to_hash' is causing the problem. Simply changing it to 'to_hsh' makes it work as expected:

```
class Array
  def to_hsh
    Hash[self.each_index.zip(self)]
  end
end

puts [50, 49, 53, 44].to_hsh

# => {0=>50, 1=>49, 2=>53, 3=>44}
```

If I try to call a 'to_hash' method on an array (without writing my own method) I get:

> NoMethodError: undefined method ‘to_hash’ for [50, 49, 53, 44]:Array

So if there's no built-in 'to_hash' method for arrays, why am I getting problems by naming my own array method 'to_hash'?

Comment: "doctor, it hurts when I do **this**" - "so don't do that". Why do you want to?

Comment: Just trying to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [Kernel#Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash) method calls `to_hash`. Which results in recursive call.

Documentation says :

> Converts arg to a Hash by calling **arg.to_hash**. Returns an empty Hash when arg is nil or [].

In the line `Hash[self.each_index.zip(self)]`, `self.each_index.zip(self)` produces an array, on which `Kernel#Hash` is calling `to_hash`. Now this `to_hash` becomes your custom `to_hash` method, which is a recursive call and produced the error as **stack level too deep (SystemStackError)**.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining that! I just rewrote the 'to_hash' method without using Hash[] and indeed, it works.